# How to get Apple Watch Unique id or UDID?

Tags: ios, apple-watch, udid

I want to get Apple Watch unique id. Is there anything available like UDID or unique identifier for developers?

Comment: I think we should wait for native SDK with this question

Comment: @sage444 The native SDK is called WatchKit and is available with Xcode 6.2, isn't it?

Comment: For those who keep hitting this page seeking how to get the UDID in order to add it to a provisioning profile, see this related SO post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29854314/debug-on-real-apple-watch-application-verification-failed/29854315

Answer (score 64, accepted):

There should be a way with Xcode 8...but I can't find it.

My solution for now: launch "Accessibility Inspector", click "Start inspection follow point" button (the one in the middle, kind of cross-hairs), click in Xcode on top of the UDID value and then copy the UDID from the inspector shown values.

Comment: Wow, neat trick. Ridiculous they've regressed on this UI and don't allow you to copy/paste.

Comment: It used to be possible in Xcode 7... Apple has a way of insulting its users recently.

Comment: Awesome, a real lifesaver! Thank you. Should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 23):

> It turns out you also have to add the UDID of the Apple Watch to the
>   Apple Developer Portal, and update your Development provisioning
>   profile to include this UDID.
>
> The UDID can be obtained in Devices window of Xcode. After pairing,
>   the info of the Apple Watch will automatically display below the info
>   of your iPhone.
>
> At the time of writing, this seems to be documented nowhere, and the
>   error message on the Apple Watch wasn't particularly helpful. So I
>   wish this try-and-error lesson would save you some hassle.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29854314/debug-on-real-apple-watch-application-verification-failed/29854315)

Comment: Thanks for this answer, if you go this route, be aware that sometime I have to restart XCode for the "Paired Watch Information" section to appear below the "Device Information" section. It works for me...

Answer (score 6):

Open XCode.

Under the menu Windows > Devices

select your iPhone (must a registered device)

Below the info about your device you will notice an headline "Paired Device Information".

One of the data provided is "Identifier". Copy the related value in your registered devices in the Developer's Portal and you are ready to go.

Comment: How do I copy it? I can neither press CMD+C nor copy via right click or select it.

Comment: Seems it was changed when they adde support for multiple apple watches and you can no longer copy it.

Comment: Yup, you can not longer copy it. <sulk> Anyone know another place it is logged or displayed in an editable field?

Comment: As of Xcode 8, you still have to write down iWatch UDID with your naked eye. No options to copy yet.

Comment: It's March 2017 and I can't believe one still cannot copy the Watch UDID!  I found a way though, but it's a total hack.  Take a screenshot of just the UDID (Cmd + Shift + 4 and lasso just the digits).  Then head over to http://www.free-ocr.com and upload that image.  It wasn't perfect though.  YMMV.

Comment: I feel your pain 

Answer (score -6):

You mean you want to access it via code written in your app? I don't think this is possible. I know it's not possible for iPhone. And apple do not accept apps that access the UDID. seems you're out of luck.

http://www.macworld.com/article/2031573/apple-sets-may-1-deadline-for-udid-iphone-5-app-changes.html

Comment: You're confusing UUID with UDID (device ID), which is needed for adhoc provisioning.