# Apple Watch, Failed to install XXX, error: Application Verification Failed

Tags: ios, installation, device, watchkit

We submitted an app recently with Apple Watch support. It installed from the App store fine but when preparing an update, we can't get it to install on a real Apple Watch anymore (fine in simulator). We have tried installing using Apple Testflight Beta and Ad Hoc builds (we, the developers do not have an actual device ourselves, just a remote tester).

The only significant thing that has changed is that we have updated to XCode 6.3 since the first release.

I have tried:

- Adding/removing beta-reports-active: [Debug on real Apple Watch: Application Verification Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29854314/debug-on-real-apple-watch-application-verification-failed)
- Verified that the deployment target is iOS 8.2.
- UUID for watch and phone are in the provisioning profiles
- Provisioning seems OK when examining IPA bundle and it can be uploaded to Apple Testflight
- Rebooting XCode, machine, etc.

The one thing that is suspicious, is that when exporting the IPA from XCode, the entitlements summary for the watch app have a circle/cross for the icon (no error is reported though). Also, the keychain-access-groups value is by default set to the Watch app's bundle id (not the host app). I have tried creating my own entitlement file to match though, and this doesn't seem to do anything. I would attach a screenshot but I don't have a 10 reputation...

Any help with this would be great. It is very hard debugging when you don't have the actual device. I have to make builds and wait for the one remote tester to try. Then repeat...

Update:

Now that I have the rep, here is the screenshot:
[image]

I did get a watch. The first time I tried to install it, it gave the same error. I then tried debugging in Xcode. It would install through Xcode (Xcode created provisioning XC profiles). Subsequently, I could get it to install using Testflight Beta. However, it still would not install for our external tester!

Comment: did you ever find out what the issue was?

Comment: You should have enough rep now to upload that screenshot if you'd like. Did you end up just submitting your app? I am in the same position and am curious if everything was fine when it finally was released to the app store.

Comment: It was released. Seems to be ok, although 1 person is having trouble installing. We don't have many data points though.

Answer (score 1):

Check your certificate entitlements. Go to apple developer center and accept the new entitlement if any. Make sure you are not using beta Xcode to publish the app.

Try validating the build before pushing to Test flight(validate in archive area) and also do check the certificate is a distribution certificate.