# "Show App on Apple Watch" Toggle Fails After Installing, Switch Flips Back to "Off", Watch App Disappears. How to fix?

Tags: ios, xcode7, watchkit, apple-watch

The environment:

- iPhone 6 device, running iOS 9.1
- Paired Apple Watch device, running watchOS 2.0 (13S5325c)
- It's a watchOS 1.0 app with no changes (runs correctly when downloaded and installed from App Store)

After building the app to my iPhone 6 physical device using Xcode Version 7.1.1 (7B1005), I then open Apple's "Watch" app, find my app, add then flip the "Show App on Apple Watch" toggle on. It appears to be installing successfully, but then, when it gets to 100%, the app icon on the watch that just finished installing disappears and the toggle switch in the Watch app on my iPhone flips back to off.

What is happening? How can I fix this?

UPDATE, FIXED:

Step 1) In Xcode go to Window > Devices. Select the iOS device your watch is paired to, to review the logs being written on the watch device.

Step 2) Hopefully the watch device logs show you an install related error that you can then use to google. In my case, I found the error "ApplicationVerificationFailed". Googling for that I found: [Debug on real Apple Watch: Application Verification Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29854314/debug-on-real-apple-watch-application-verification-failed) Which tipped me off to provisioning profile related issues. Somehow my watch was not tied to the provision profile loaded into Xcode. So, I added my watch device to my provisioning profile in dev center via Safari, downloaded that provisioning profile to my comp and double clicked to install. This fixed my apple watch install errors.

Comment: Just thought I'd add that this is repeatedly happening to me today (iOS 9.3.3, WatchOS 2.2.2, Xcode 7.3.1).  I fixed it once by re-downloading my provisioning profile like you, but it just started happening *again* after I made a minor code change.  I'll update if I find any info on what might cause it to re-occur.

Comment: Definitely an oversight on provisioning profiles for me, with devices at least. In terms of simulators, not so sure. Sometimes pairing has been working, but mostly not. Using Xamarin.