# How to get Apple Watch UDID with Xcode 7.3?

Tags: xcode, apple-watch, xcode7.3

I'm trying to add the UDID of the Apple Watch to the Apple Developer Portal but in Xcode 7.3 you can not copy UDID to clipboard.

[image]

You can see UDID but can not copy.

Comment: [File a bug report](https://bugreport.apple.com/).  It's an unfortunate layout change due to how more than one paired watch can now appear in Devices.

Answer (score 3):

This issue still exists in Xcode 8.2. You can use Accessibility Inspector app (which is part of the Xcode installation) to select the UDID label. The inspector will then show the UDID as a selectable text where you can copy it.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than copying the UUID, and manually uploading it to the portal, it is possible to build the Apple Watch App target, selecting the "myPhone + myAppleWatch" target to run it on (it'll be your device names). It will tell you the Watch doesn't match any provisioning profile, and offer to fix it for you. When you accept, it will do the upload for you.

More here, which is not per se a duplicate, but addresses the solution outlined here: [Debug on real Apple Watch: Application Verification Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29854314/debug-on-real-apple-watch-application-verification-failed/29854315)