# How to get apple watch serial number programmatically using swift2?

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

I am developing an apple watch app where I need device serial id. How do I get it programmatically?

Below question is unanswered.
[How to get Apple Watch Unique id or UDID or Serial Number Programatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32102202/how-to-get-apple-watch-unique-id-or-udid-or-serial-number-programatically)

and there is no other link to fetch it programmatically.

Comment: Why would you need it? Apple doesn't make device identifiers available anymore.

Comment: hmm looks like I have to generate my own token to identify the watch. If I generate my own token and save it in my server then is there any way to save it in watch like localstorage of html5 so that every time my watch makes an http request it sends this token and I can identify the watch?

Comment: I have asked this as a separate question to get answer little quick as more people will have a look at a new question.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38156268/saving-a-token-in-apple-watch-for-authentication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't access the serial number. This was possible in the past on the phone and was deprecated by Apple. After that people used to generate an id using mac address, this was deprecated and not supported as well shortly after

1) Your server should generate the id on first login, after that you can store the id in the keychain in case the user delete/reinstall the app so you can restore state for the user

2) You can use alternate methods to get an id, e.g. facebook login, gamecenter..